# Laravel : How to get anchor tag value in variable and use this variable in the input field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.5

And this `$emp->id` gives me an accurate `id`, so it's not an issue I just get `id={{$emp->id}}` from this? Help please.

```
<a href="{{'/employee'}}?id={{$emp->id}}" type="button" name="u_id" > Apply Attribute </a>
```

After Click on Apply Button the value, using this it always returns the 1st user id, or if I use this outside from foreach loop it will give me the 2nd user id, so if we get the when click on href and want to store this id value in a variable and use this in the value? So please help me to get the value from the anchor tag? I am happy if you solve this problem. Thanks developers in advance.

```
<form action="{{'/rating'}}" method="post">
 {{csrf_field()}} 

 <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$emp->id}}" />

 <input type="submit"  style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="btn btn-success pull-right" name="apply" value="Apply"/>

</form>
```

Comment: Where is the `foreach` loop ? and where you're getting those values?

Comment: @foreach($employ as $emp)
                                <tr> 
                                    <td>{{$emp->name}}</td> </tr>
                                    }
                                   ?>
  <a href="{{'/employee'}}?id={{$emp->id}}" type="button" name="u_id" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Apply Attribute
  </a>

Comment: Edit the question plz with further details so we could help.

Comment: i am not getting value , but we show at the bottom after i am scroll the mouse to the Apply Attribute button then will show me at the bottom of window ,

Comment: Okk i will edit the question

Comment: Sir just simple tell me how we get the value from href="" for example <a href="Hello" >Apply</a> We simply get the hello from the href , is it possible???

Comment: You would get it using Javascript ?? where is your code ? when you want to get this `href` ?! you should give us more details.

Comment: my question is my code , i am just use javascript everywhere to get the href value , in variable and use this in php code , is it? and how?

Comment: Sir you just suppose that i have a href="?id="GoodBaby"" and get this GoodBaby in the variable and use this variable in the input field? is it possible? and thanks sir in advance

Comment: You're welcome sir, but without knowing the langage you want to use and when you want to get this param I can't answer... Sorry.

Comment: This is the same question you've asked earlier..you are very vague and it is unclear what you precisely want.

Comment: Zakaria Ancharki Check out this is my answer , now finally i did this , and thanks sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Href Like That:

```
<a href="{{$emp->id}}" type="button"  id="uu_id" class="btn btn-primary uu" 
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Apply Attribute </a>
```

Using This Script To get Value from Href:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".uu").click(function(event) {
        var u_id = $(this).attr('href');
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("hiddenVal").value = u_id;
    });

 });
</script>
```

And in your Form like this:

```
<form action="{{'/rating'}}" method="post">
 {{csrf_field()}} 

 <input type="submit"  style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="btn btn-success 
   pull-right" name="apply" value="Apply"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="hiddenVal" id="hiddenVal" />
</form>
```

And Last How to get this Value in the Controller And save to Database:

```
public function store(Request $request)
 {
   $rates = new Rating;
   $user_id = $_POST['hiddenVal'];
   $rates->user_id = $user_id;    
   $rates->save();
   return redirect('/employee');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you pulling {{'/employee'}} ?

```
@foreach($employ as $emp)
   <tr> 
      <td>{{$emp->name}}</td>
   <td> 
      <a href="/employee?id={{$emp->id}}" type="button" name="u_id"class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> 
         Apply Attribute 
      </a>
   </td>
@endforeach
```